# A flicker issue is coming while using ng-show / ng-hide with any css animation property

Tags: css, angularjs

I have 3 buttons with a class myBtn with the following property:-

```
.myBtn {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  color: red;
  background: white;
}
```

And I have 3 buttons in the view like below

```
<button class="myBtn " data-ng-show="view.showAdd">Add</button>
<button class="myBtn " data-ng-show="view.showEdit">Edit</button>
<button class="myBtn " data-ng-show="view.showDelete">Delete</button>
```

In my controller I am showing the add button for the first time and hiding the other edit and delete button. But edit and delete button are in visible for a fraction of second for the first time.

```
$scope.view ={

  showAdd: true,
  showEdit: false,
  showDelete: false
}
```

If I am using ng-if then it is solving the problem But I have some other functionality to choose ng-show.

***Question***

How to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

After spending lot of time I came an conclusion that because of the transition all property , it is working for display none/ block.

As ng-show and ng-hide internally work using display block/none, so it showing the transition effect. And I am getting the flicker issue.

So the solution is either 
Remove the transition property Or else use ng-if.

Thought to share this info....

With ng-if also the problem is not getting solved. It is working for the first time. But when you want to hide it again it is showing the flicker issue.
So I overriden the transition property for display property like below:-

```
      transition: display 0s;
     -webkit-transition: display 0s;
     -moz-transition: display 0s;
     -ms-transition: display 0s;
     -o-transition: display 0s;
```

It gave me the correct result and not other functionality breakage.

Hope it will be useful for others

Thanks all